# Where does Kindle Cloud Reader keeps downloaded books, under Linux?

Tags: amazon, ebook-management, kindle-cloud-reader

I'm a Linux Mint user and I use the Kindle Cloud Reader app for Google Chrome to read ebooks linked to my Amazon account.

I'd like to know where does this app, on my computer, stores the ebooks that are downloaded for offline reading.

Comment: I did some research and found out that the apps *seems* to store its data inside /home/<your_username>/.config/chromium/<your_profile>/Application Cache/ (note that I use openSUSE, so the exact path can be different); this directory however doesn't  seem to contains the ebooks in plain usable data, they seem to be hardcoded in binary form.

Comment: Yes indeed. However, as its in binary format so basically useless for me. Nevertheless, Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: You could try to ask at the MobileRead forums too, maybe these guys can give you some more help if you don't get many more responses here. Please report back if you do, I'm interested in this topic too :-)